# how to keep video playing with screen off in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, video-streaming

In android this would be implemented using. a service. Is there anyway to keep flutters [video player](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player) running when the screen is off? Is doesn't have to be this plugin. Any solution is welcome!

Comment: Maybe we need a background service in this case.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: probably not what you're looking for: but you could add a wake lock to the manifest

Comment: Normally when we are playing video we manage it with wakelock so screen won't get off. So this could be the option if you don't find option for screen off.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, there is no video player background service as far as I know and the developer him/her self must implement this service,
there is a poor package named **flutter_playout** you can use but its customization is complex.
here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_playout

Answer (score 0):

I have an Idea!

May be due to my English and i am posting first time in stack overflow. Some mistakes can come.

Better Player having the option to make it happen. In better player there is an option to enable PIP(Picture in picture) option, when enable that, the video will play in small box. Then you can lock the phone audio never brake. Almost background play option we can do without a hardwork in this way.!! Also you can customize the notification of that video. Just refer this documentation.

[BetterPlayer documentation](https://jhomlala.github.io/betterplayer/#/notificationconfiguration)

I just write down the major part of the Better player code here

```
 BetterPlayerDataSource dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
       BetterPlayerDataSourceType.file,
       widget.videoLink,
       notificationConfiguration: BetterPlayerNotificationConfiguration(
         showNotification: true,
         title: <Here your video name>,
       )
    );
```

[image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8XLs.jpg)